# lowpass filtering in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I am writing a code in vhdl for image processing and I learned that in order to blur a picture, that picture must be lowpass filtered. I know about lowpass filters but I dont know how to apply this idea to the image I am trying to blur. How can I do blur a picture in vhdl using this idea?

Comment: You'll need to look at DSP, and 2-D convolution with kernels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple weighted average of pixels surrounding the target pixel will do that. Clearly you have to do it in 2D. Step and repeat for each pixel. There are a lot of calculations so try and limit yourself to maybe a 3x3 array or a 5x5 to begin with. Make sure you update pixels to a new target picture and don't overwrite the original (until you have finished).

[image]

This is a FIR type algorithm. And the one below is a gaussian smoothing 5 x 5 filter: -

[image]

[Picture source](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/gsmooth.htm)

Notice the symmetry of the weighting factors with the most weight being given to the middle pixel.

Comment: thanks a lot so if I understand clearly to blur a picture I must find avarage of values of pixels surrounding my target pixels and I must put that average value onto that target pixel right

Comment: so from this technique can I sharp an image following reverse steps as in blurring

Comment: Yes you can. You are then enhancing the brightness differences between pixels aka high pass filtering. A weighted average for low pass filtering is the best method.